# Mongo - Aggregation of sum of values based on name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to perform an aggregate function to calculate the sum of the cost and margin values based on the name value. So if multiple results have the name "Fake Provider' I want the sum of the cost results and the sum of the margin results.

Query statement:

```
Pharmacy.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    $and: [{ 'prescription.status': 'Ready for Pickup' }]
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    'insurance.primary.name': 1,
    'prescription.financial.cost': 1,
    'prescription.financial.margin': 1
  }
}
])
```

Results are similar to:

```
[
  {
      "_id": "5cab98cd293bd54e94c40461",
      "insurance": {
          "primary": {
              "name": "Fake Provider 1"
          }
      },
      "prescription": [
          {
              "financial": {
                  "cost": "2.89",
                  "margin": "5.60"
              }
          },
          {
              "financial": {
                  "cost": "0.88",
                  "margin": "1.24"
              }
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "_id": "5cab98d0293bd54e94c40470",
      "insurance": {
          "primary": {
              "name": "Fake Provider 1"
          }
      },
      "prescription": [
          {
              "financial": {
                  "cost": "3.22",
                  "margin": "9.94"
              }
          },
          {
              "financial": {
                  "cost": "2.57",
                  "margin": "9.29"
              }
          },
          {
              "financial": {
                  "cost": "2.03",
                  "margin": "10.17"
              }
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

I have attempted to create a group statement without any luck. Also, the cost and margin values are currently stored as strings.

```
  $group: {
    _id: '$insurance.primary.name',
    Financial: {
      $push: {
        id: '$insurance.primary.name',
        name: '$insurance.primary.name',
        cost: '$prescription.financial.cost',
        margin: '$prescription.financial.margin'
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to get results similar to:

```
 [
{
  "primaryInsurance": "Fake Provider 1",
  "totalFinancialCost": "11.59",
  "totalFinancialMargin": "36.24"
},
{
  "primaryInsurance": "Fake Provider 2",
  "totalFinancialCost": "12.82",
  "totalFinancialMargin": "22.16"
}
]
```

I think I have a solution that returns the results using a find and projection then using javascript to map thru the results and perform the addition. However, I would prefer to do this at the Database level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first unwind the 'prescription' field then perform a group. Try this pipeline:

```
let pipeline = [
{
  $unwind: {
    path: '$prescription'
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: '$insurance.primary.name',
    totalFinancialCost: {
      $sum: { $convert: { input: '$prescription.financial.cost', to: "decimal" } } 
    },
    totalFinancialMargin: {
      $sum: { $convert: { input: '$prescription.financial.margin', to: "decimal" } } 
    }
  }
}]
```

Notice how the values are converted to decimal in order to perform the sum.

Comment: I receive this error - MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$convert' . looks like im using v3.6.3 . It's likely not available in this version.

Comment: Try using this statement:
$sum: { $toDecimal: '$prescription.financial.margin' }

Comment: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$toDecimal' Both of these are only available in version 4.0.+ . If its not possible in v.3.6.3 I will upgrade and then retry.

Comment: The conversion functions are available after v4.0, so either update or change the datatype.